# Preload objects using unity config

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container

How do I need to config unity to preload all registered types? What I mean is that I have one configuration for unity and it looks like this

```
<alias alias="IMyObject" type="...">
<alias alias="MyObject" type="...">
<container>
    <register type="IMyObject" mapTo="MyObject">
        <constructor />
    </register>
</container>
```

And then in code when I try to resolve from unity container

```
 var newObject = container.Resolve<IMyObject>();
```

I got this error

*"The type name or alias MyObject could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name."*

But when before Resolving I make reference to MyObject somewhere in code, everything is fine. So my question is, how can i prevent this error using unity config?

**EDIT**

It looks like the assembly of MyObject is not loaded, because I'm not using MyObject in whole project. I have it only registered in unity.config.

Comment: Can you post the full `alias` config line? Maybe there is a problem how you specify the `type` attribute.

Comment: it seems you have a problem with the configuration; double check the namespace and dll name of the IMyObject and MyObject.

Comment: You need to use the assembly qualified name of the type in your config e.g. `<alias alias="MyObject"            type="MyLibrary.MyNamespace.MyObject, MyLibrary" />`

Comment: I'm sorry I think my explanation wasn't very good. There is no problem with correct assembly names, this works just fine. Problem is that when I don't make instance of MyObject somewhere in code, I got the error. For example: `container.Resolve<IMyObject>();` -> exception is thrown. But when I add line for example `var foo = new MyObject;` before or after resolving from container, no exception is thrown and everything works fine. My full alias looks like this `<alias alias="ICacheProvider" type="Infrastructure.Caching.ICacheProvider, Infrastructure.Caching" />`

Comment: Have you deployed the assembly containing the MyObject type to the bin directory of your program? VS won't do this automatically unless you've got a reference to the assembly. And without the actual .dll in the bin directory, nothing will be able to load it.